# Magento 2 Issue with "Not Registered Handle" on all the sales sections?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, sales

If I go to "Sales" under Magento 2, I have several menu options. And every single one of those options has an error relating to that section:

Orders: Not registered handle sales_order_grid_data_source
Invoices: Not registered handle sales_order_invoice_grid_data_source
Shipments: Not registered handle sales_order_shipment_grid_data_source
Credit Memos: Not registered handle sales_order_creditmemo_grid_data_source

And so on. I was on Magento 2.0.x earlier and the issue wasn't there. I don't know when the issue appeared because this store is in development and not active. But I've since updated to 2.1.0 then 2.1.3 this week, and not sure when the problem occurred. Anything helpful would be great.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Okay so I found the problem. I found another stackexchange topic that didn't seem to be 100% related because it was a different module, however the exact same scenario was occurring. You can find the discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39763550/magento-2-1-1-admin-content-pages-not-loading-handle-not-registered

The main thing was that I didn't create any custom modules, but I did install a few modules from third parties. I guess I just assumed these would have been updated, but they were manually installed not with composer, there were minor issues with the setup of the modules file structure. Being new to Magento I looked at the topic above and was just looking at the Magento file structure, but then it clicked I needed to look at the file structure of the modules.

Once, I investigated each of the modules I had installed, I looked in the etc/adminhtml directory for each and I found a few of them had a di.xml file in that directory, and also an etc/di.xml. So I opened both files, compared them, and combined them. I only added what was missing from the adminhtml path into the etc/di.xml path. Then I renamed the etc/adminhtml/di.xml to bak.di.xml just to back it up. I cleared and flushed the cache, and everything is working again.

It appears to me that this is a change from 2.0.x to 2.1.x. Most modules will be fine working from 2.0.x to 2.1.x but that file structure is what caused my issues.

Comment: Thank you Jason, I did as you mentioned here, though I did not copy all the code of di.xml of adminhtml folder to etc/di.xml but I commented all the code of di.xml of adminhtml folder & all the things are working fine now :)
So yes you are right that there is something with di.xml in adminhtml folder.

Comment: I made an answer what is causing this after i got this issue myself, Thanks for the lead to the solution

Comment: So, we cannot create di.xml under adminhtml?

Answer (score 49):

The problem here is that someone defined a handle in the `etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

search for something like this

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="NameOfHandle" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Something\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<virtualType name="Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Something\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">NameOfTable</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Something</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Do not search for the handle that he can not find. Just go over etc/adminhtml/di.xml in your modules and search for

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
```

Move that bit of code to `etc/di.xml` instead of `etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: if I move the <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory"> to etc/di.xml file it's not working, but the "Not registered handle" error gone

Comment: What is your di.xml noNamespaceSchemaLocation ? be sure it is set to urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd

Comment: the Actual problem is with di.xml  After checking that this problem will solved.. :)

Comment: @CompactCode i faced same issue but code also available in etc/di.xml not in etc/adminhtml/di.xml still same issue exists.

Comment: Check this https://www.hungersoft.com/info/not-a-registered-handle-data-source-magento2-admin-grid for more info

Comment: @hungersoft Nice plug :D

Comment: It worked, but that's reeealy odd

Answer (score 12):

The self-provided answer from @jason-diehl doesn't really explain this issue, and I believe includes some incorrect information.

I ran into this issue when developing a custom module and testing the admin grid.  I could see the container with the "Add ____" button, but a single message: `Not registered handle ________`.  After looking into things I realized that I had specified a `<dataSource>` name in my `view/adminhtml/ui_component/my_module_controller_listing.xml` file which was not included in my `etc/di.xml` file as a named `<item>` in the list of collections for the `Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory` type.

Once I adjusted the name of the data source in my listing to match the name of the collection in `etc/di.xml`, the error was gone.

So to summarize: When you specify a data source to use in your adminhtml grid listing UI component(s), you *must* make sure the `name` attribute of your data source is specified as the name of a collection under the `<type>` tag of `Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory`.

Comment: Truly helped me. It really explained the issue and should be better rated imho :)

Comment: This is a good answer. In the latest official doc, adminhtml grid requires di.xml configuration for `CollectionFactory`.. (not sure whose great idea it was to make setting up vanilla grid through "DI")

Answer (score 9):

**"Move that bit of code to `etc/di.xml` instead of `etc/adminhtml/di.xml`"**

Everyone is suggesting for moving code from `etc/adminhtml/di.xml` to  `etc/di.xml`. Don't understand. `why to move ?` When gone inside this then found that `etc/adminhtml/di.xml` has greater priority over `etc/di.xml` i.e. if any of the single module inside `app/code/`, if defined `di.xml` `datasource` inside `etc/adminhtml/di.xml`, then it will not look for `etc/di.xml` for same `type` in other modules, and modules stopped and show error `Not registered handle`.

so, if you are going to define `type` in code section be sure that it is in a right place, and as I can see people have made `etc/di.xml` as Right place to define `type` for `Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory`.

for example -

`etc/di.xml`

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
```

`etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
```

When same type is defined in above two files, then priority will be given to `etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

I define it inside, `etc/adminhtml/di.xml`, have a look :)

https://github.com/gitamitgit/sample-admin-module

Comment: You can define it there but it will break your other modules. Infact if you search the codebase for the declarations in di.xml files - not a single module declares this in etc/adminhtml/di.xml

Comment: @ol'bobdole On Magento 2.3, I see that 284 `di.xml` files are directly in `etc/`, and 255 `di.xml` files are in `etc/some_area/`. Those areas are frontend, adminhtml, webapi_soap, webapi_rest, graphql, and others.

Comment: @dotancohen in some instances, for the type being defined, it matters what area it is defined in. 
`Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory` is one of them.

Comment: I've found that if a new module is defined, using `etc/adminhtml/di.xml` should work without issue.  But if you are overwritting an existing `<item>` defined by an existing module (ie. `vendor/magento/`) and that module initially declared it at `etc/di.xml`, then using `etc/adminhtml/di.xml` will result in breaking other modules that depend on that `<item>`.

So to summarize, new modules should be able to use `etc/adminhtml/di.xml` safely, but when overwritting a module use the same tier as that parent module.

Answer (score 1):

For My case, I did all. But forgot to run `bin/magento setup:di:compile`

after run its working.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the di.xml to /etc does not help in my case, i also added the following lines into my di.xml (i'm rewriting the sales_order_grid_data_source)

```
<item name="sales_order_invoice_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\Grid\Collection</item>
<item name="sales_order_shipment_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Grid\Collection</item>
<item name="sales_order_creditmemo_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Creditmemo\Grid\Collection</item>
<item name="sales_order_view_invoice_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\Orders\Grid\Collection</item>
<item name="sales_order_view_shipment_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Order\Grid\Collection</item>
<item name="sales_order_view_creditmemo_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Creditmemo\Order\Grid\Collection</item>
```