# Activating custom grid in magento2 causes other grid to throws error

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, di

I have created a custom grid with following di.xml

`di.xml`

```
<preference for="\Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\InlineEdit" type="Namespace\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\InlineEdit" />

 <type name="\Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="school_district_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Agencyzipmapping\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

<type name="Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Agencyzipmapping\Grid\Collection">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">agency_zipcode_mapping</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Agencyzipmapping</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Whenever I activate / enable my module, other grids in admin panel show following error:
`Not registered handle`

I tried changing type to virtual type as mentioned over [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/220761). That didn't work out.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
namespace 
Namespace\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Agencyzipmapping\Grid;

use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface as EventManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\AggregationInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Ecs\Addressautofill\Model\ResourceModel\Agencyzipmapping\Collection as schoolCollection;

class Collection extends schoolCollection implements SearchResultInterface
{
/**
 * Aggregations
 * 
 * @var AggregationInterface
 */
protected $aggregations;

/**
 * constructor
 * 
 * @param EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory
 * @param LoggerInterface $logger
 * @param FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy
 * @param EventManagerInterface $eventManager
 * @param string $mainTable
 * @param string $eventPrefix
 * @param string $eventObject
 * @param string $resourceModel
 * @param AdapterInterface $connection
 * @param AbstractDb $resource
 * @param $model
 */
public function __construct(
    EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
    LoggerInterface $logger,
    FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
    EventManagerInterface $eventManager,
    $mainTable,
    $eventPrefix,
    $eventObject,
    $resourceModel,
    AdapterInterface $connection = null,
    AbstractDb $resource = null,
    $model = 'Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document'
)
{
    parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection, $resource);
    $this->_eventPrefix = $eventPrefix;
    $this->_eventObject = $eventObject;
    $this->_init($model, $resourceModel);
    $this->setMainTable($mainTable);
}


/**
 * @return AggregationInterface
 */
public function getAggregations()
{
    return $this->aggregations;
}

/**
 * @param AggregationInterface $aggregations
 * @return $this
 */
public function setAggregations($aggregations)
{
    $this->aggregations = $aggregations;
}


/**
 * Retrieve all ids for collection
 * Backward compatibility with EAV collection
 *
 * @param int $limit
 * @param int $offset
 * @return array
 */
public function getAllIds($limit = null, $offset = null)
{
    return $this->getConnection()->fetchCol($this->_getAllIdsSelect($limit, $offset), $this->_bindParams);
}

/**
 * Get search criteria.
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface|null
 */
public function getSearchCriteria()
{
    return null;
}

/**
 * Set search criteria.
 *
 * @param SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria
 * @return $this
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
 */
public function setSearchCriteria(SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria = null)
{
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get total count.
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getTotalCount()
{
    return $this->getSize();
}

/**
 * Set total count.
 *
 * @param int $totalCount
 * @return $this
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
 */
public function setTotalCount($totalCount)
{
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set items list.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataInterface[] $items
 * @return $this
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
 */
public function setItems(array $items = null)
{
    return $this;
}

protected function _initSelect() 
{
    $this->addFilterToMap('id', 'city_master.id');
    $this->addFilterToMap('id', 'agency_master.id');
    $this->addFilterToMap('id', 'zipcode_master.id');

    parent::_initSelect();

    $cityMasterTable = $this->getTable('city_master');
    $this->getSelect()->join($cityMasterTable, 'main_table.city_id = city_master.id', ['city_name']);

    $agencyMasterTable = $this->getTable('agency_master');
    $this->getSelect()->join($agencyMasterTable, 'main_table.agency_id = agency_master.id', ['agency_name']);

    $zipcodeMasterTable = $this->getTable('zipcode_master');
    $this->getSelect()->join($zipcodeMasterTable, 'main_table.zipcode_id = zipcode_master.id', ['zipcode']);

    $stateTable = $this->getTable('directory_country_region');
    $this->getSelect()->join($stateTable, 'main_table.state_id = directory_country_region.region_id', ['default_name']);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

replace di.xml below code

```
<type name="Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Agencyzipmapping\Grid\Collection">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">agency_zipcode_mapping</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Agencyzipmapping</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

to

```
<virtualType name="Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Agencyzipmapping\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">agency_zipcode_mapping</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Agencyzipmapping</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>



    <virtualType name="MyGirdFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
                <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <virtualType name="MyGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Namespace\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Agencyzipmapping\Collection</argument>
            <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">MyGirdFilterPool</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, i have tried this method but isnt working and i also moved my etc/adminhtml/di.xml to etc/di.xml

Comment: can you please post your collection code

Comment: i have added my collection class below pls check